# Try / Catch error

Tags: java, try-catch

Can any one explain why my try/catch wont work? I am trying to make that if a user enters a letter it will get the error message or if they enter a number not in my options they also get the error. All i seem to get is the usual red line errors when entering a letter and nothing happens if i enter for example the number 6.

```
public void menu()
     {
            System.out.println("Welcome to your Payroll System");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Please enter your choice below from the following options");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("View all current weekly employees = 1 ");
            System.out.println("View all current monthly employees = 2 ");
            System.out.println("Delete an employee = 3 ");
            System.out.println("Add an employee = 4 ");
            System.out.println("Print an employee payslip = 5");
            System.out.println("To exit the system = 0 ");

            // allows user to enter number of choice and this reflects which statement is ran in userChoice method
            tempvar = sc.nextInt();
            userChoice();
     }



            public void userChoice() 

            {  
               try
               {
                // if user enters 1 it prints out the employee list.
                if (tempvar == 1) 
                {
                    w.printWeekly();    
                } 
                if (tempvar == 2) 
                {
                    mo.printMonthly();
                } 
                if (tempvar == 3) 
                {
                    e.deleteEmployee();
                } 
                if (tempvar == 4) 
                {
                    e.addEmployee();
                } 
                if (tempvar == 5) 
                {
                    mo.createPayslip(); 
                }

                if (tempvar == 0) // if user hits 0 it allows them to exit the programme

                {
                    System.out.println("You have exited the system");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }

               catch(InputMismatchException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Error in the data you have entered please try again");

                }

                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Error in the data you have entered please try again");

                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have raised an exception? It appears that you never throw an exception to try catch phase. You must throw an InputMismatchException

Comment: Please provide your error so we can help you

Comment: if i enter 'a' i get:xception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1118)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:1473)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:1437)
 at paySystem.Console.userChoice(Console.java:40)
 at paySystem.Console.menu(Console.java:32)
 at paySystem.Main.main(Main.java:8)

Comment: then wrap your try catch to Scanner too, you must place the line the caused exception to catch it

Comment: there is absolutely no code to handle a '6' here. You need to throw an exception if you want to catch it.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, hope that helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you did not raise an exception in the program, to do a custom exception raise

```
throw new InputMismatchException("This exception is going to be handled elsewhere");
```

## Edit 1

You must wrap your try-catch block around the line that raised exception. To handle it for your scanner

wrap it with

```
 public void menu()
 {
        System.out.println("Welcome to your Payroll System");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Please enter your choice below from the following options");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("View all current weekly employees = 1 ");
        System.out.println("View all current monthly employees = 2 ");
        System.out.println("Delete an employee = 3 ");
        System.out.println("Add an employee = 4 ");
        System.out.println("Print an employee payslip = 5");
        System.out.println("To exit the system = 0 ");

        // allows user to enter number of choice and this reflects which statement is ran in userChoice method
        try {
             tempvar = sc.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
             System.out.println("...");
        }
        userChoice();
 }
```

Comment: where do i place that in the code?

Comment: your tempvar = sc.nextInt() caused it, place it there, I will edit it

Comment: still unsure, can you post all the code, i put it where i think you meant but now the rest of my code doesnt run properly

Comment: It SHOULD handle what you wanted now

Comment: almost there!! get the error message now thanks but it also below outputs the message "You have exited the system" from option 0

Comment: you can also print one more message inside the catch. Such as if his entry is wrong, tell him the message, tell him he left it, and System.exit(1);

Another approach is to set the tempvar to 0 , then call the method userChoice(). You may also let the user enter again by using loop

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing happening because you don't do anything specific in case you don't get a number that is a member of your predefined set. If the user enters `6`, none of the `if` conditions will be validated and your method will smoothly complete.

You need to throw an exception of type `InputMismatchException`, otherwise the `catch` block is nonsense.

If I were you, I'd write a `switch` statement like this:

```
try
    {
    switch(tempvar):
        case 1:
            w.printWeekly();    
            break;
        case 2:
            mo.printMonthly();
            break;
        case 3: 
            e.deleteEmployee();
            break;
        case 4:
            e.addEmployee();
            break;
        case 5: 
            mo.createPayslip(); 
            break;
        case 0:
            System.out.println("You have exited the system");
            System.exit(0);
        default:
            throw new InputMismatchException();
        }
catch(InputMismatchException e)
{
     System.out.println("Error in the data you have entered please try again");
}
```

Nevertheless, it's not a recommended pattern to throw exceptions that you know your `catch` block will catch. You can find other solution for handling the erroneous cases, e.g. you can move your print statement directly to the `default` option.

Comment: Umm, I think his comment was saying that the error raised in the scanner line in menu()